# IBM MQ XMS for Net System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file

Tags: c#, jms, ibm-mq

My `net-API` with xms just can not connect to a remote manager while `java-API` with jms can connect to the same one.

1.i had added ip address into hosts file.

there is the log of the error.

```
 2013-09-24 15:55:04,620 [10] DEBUG line267 Com.Tsystems.Aviation.Imf.Client.connector.CmsConnector - The connection initialized param is, host: AIXMQ214, destination: IN.LQ.FSS1.FQDB, port: 1414, Qmgr: QM70IMF_01, user: aviation, ccsid: 819, channel: SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
    2013-09-24 15:55:05,086 [10] ERROR line463 Com.Tsystems.Aviation.Imf.Client.connector.CmsConnector - create CMS connection failed on IN.LQ.FSS1.FQDB IBM.XMS.XMSException: CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
       at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.ManagedNmqiMQ.NmqiConnect(String name, NmqiConnectOptions pNmqiConnectOpts, MQConnectOptions cno, Hconn parentHconn, Phconn pHconn, Int32& compCode, Int32& reason)
       at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqConnection..ctor(NmqiEnvironment nmqiEnv, NmqiMQ nmqiMQ, XmsPropertyContext connectProps)
       at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqConnectionFactory.CreateV7ProviderConnection(XmsPropertyContext connectionProps). During execution of the specified method an exception was thrown by another component. See the linked exception for more information.
       at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqConnectionFactory.CreateProviderConnection(XmsPropertyContext connectionProps)
       at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection(String userID, String password)
       at Com.Tsystems.Aviation.Imf.Client.connector.CmsConnector.Connect(CmsConnectorType connectorType) in D:\Aviation\C#\com.tsystems.aviation.imf.client\connector\CmsConnector.cs:line 412

    Linked Exception : System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
       at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.ManagedNmqiMQ.NmqiConnect(String name, NmqiConnectOptions pNmqiConnectOpts, MQConnectOptions cno, Hconn parentHconn, Phconn pHconn, Int32& compCode, Int32& reason)
       at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqConnection..ctor(NmqiEnvironment nmqiEnv, NmqiMQ nmqiMQ, XmsPropertyContext connectProps)
       at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqConnectionFactory.CreateV7ProviderConnection(XmsPropertyContext connectionProps)
```

Comment: This is a strange error, I have not come across. My suggestion would be to raise a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Thx for ur reply. I have no idea, yet.

Comment: Do you any further details?

Comment: I don't have any. I have 2 server, one with MQ7.0.1.9, another is MQ7.0.1.10. My program is use dlls of MQ7.0.1.10. This happens when i try to connect MQ7.0.1.9. But it's fine to connect MQ7.0.1.10. I don't know... ╮(╯▽╰)╭